# Azure EventHub: offline event buffering/queueing possible?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I can't find any definitive answer here. My IoT service needs to tollerate flaky connections. Currently, I manage a local cache myself and retry a cloud-blob transfer as often as required. Could I replace this with an Azure EventHub service? i.e. will the EventHub client (on IoT-Core) buffer events until the connection is available? If so, where is the info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem so according to:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/

You are resposible for sending and caching it seems:

> Send asynchronously and send at scale
>
> You can also send events to an Event Hub asynchronously. Sending
>   asynchronously can increase the rate at which a client is able to send
>   events. Both the Send and SendBatch methods are available in
>   asynchronous versions that return a Task object. While this technique
>   can increase throughput, it can also cause the client to continue to
>   send events even while it is being throttled by the Event Hubs service
>   and can result in the client **experiencing failures or lost messages** if
>   not properly implemented. In addition, you can use the RetryPolicy
>   property on the client to control client retry options.

Comment: Thanks for finding this. IMHO, real-world IoT must tollerate connection failures without data loss, so I'll stick to my Brokered Service Bus solution and check the RetryPolicy mentioned to see if can queue/cache multiple messages for me and retry until the connection exists.

Comment: ... see if anybody has more info before I mark as answered.

Comment: No problem, even with MQTT there doesn't seem to be a client cache. The protocols for IoT focus on an online scenario, being offline will be different for each device and application, so no solution there I guess.

Comment: This seem to be the extent at the moment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-retry-service-specific/ Retry is not the same as buffering, but may be adequate in some cases. ServiceBus appears to have the best cards here. No mention of Event Hub.