# Azure IoT Hubs: offline storage of messages

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is there any functionality within the Azure IoT device SDKs to ensure that a message is sent to the hub from a device in the event of a loss of connectivity and subsequent termination and restart (after connectivity is restored) of the application sending the message?

I am struggling to find anything about this in the documentation; I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484744/azure-eventhub-offline-event-buffering-queueing-possible), however it has not been updated in nearly 2 years and I suspect (hope) things have moved on since then.

The application will be WPF, running on Windows 10 Professional if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/benefits-of-using-the-azure-iot-sdks-in-your-azure-iot-solution/) has a section on the reliability features in the SDKs.  We will have more documentation on this soon.  You may also want to implement some heat beat mechanism so devices can auto-reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but the blog does not really explain whether or not messages will be stored locally and/or how to make that happen. If I am to use an IoT hub, I need to know that a message will get through irrespective of what happens to the application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement that functionality is check the callback function result and the parent  (SendConfirmationCallback - IoTHubClient_LL_SendEventAsync in SDK-C). With this You can check the quantity of messages without confirmation OK and restart your process of azure or Internet connection.